# What preposition with verb "to host"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, prepositions

I tried to find some information about this but I'm guessing this verb, in this meaning, isn't very common yet, hence no rules.

My friend asked me whether the following sentence was correct:

> Gareth hosted Juliette on her second trip to Milan

It didn't sound right to me. I told her to rewrite it as **Gareth hosted Juliette when she visited Milan for the second time** but I can't stop thinking how to phrase it correctly if I wanted to keep that exact structure.

- host somebody for a trip
- host somebody during a trip
- host somebody on a trip

"During" seems okay if the visit was a stop, part of a bigger trip. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with

> (1) Gareth hosted Juliette on her second trip to Milan.

It does seem to me that Gareth  acted as a host for Juliette  during the travel as well as during the stay in Milan, but it might not mean that.  The suggested alternative:

> (2) Gareth hosted Juliette when she visited Milan for the second time

is a bit wordier, and suggests that  Gareth  acted as a host for Juliette only during the stay in Milan, not on the travel to and from Milan. But it i8s also quite natural, and the difference in meanign is at best slight.

> (1A) Gareth hosted Juliette for her second trip to Milan.

seems to have much the same meaning as (1), and to be just as acceptable. The use of "during" would also be acceptable, and need not imply that the trip is part of a larger excursion.